# R documentation, how to force Rcmd Rd2pdf to automatically break an overfull line in examples R-like section?

Tags: r, latex, line-breaks

My package passed `Rcmd check` successfully. but in constructed PDF format of R documentation, within the examples section, half of the line (R code) is out of the paper. I also found another CRAN submitted package, `ftsa` , that suffer from overfulling in a line too, see `ftsa` [Reference manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ftsa/ftsa.pdf).

I guess this 
problem roots in the behavior of the `verbatim` environment in Latex. However there are some Latex packages to deal with this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/verbatim-environment-that-can-break-too-long-lines, but I do not know how to use them with `Rcmd`.

1. In dealing with these cases, why `Rcmd check` does not show any error, warnings or    note as Latex does?
2. How can I force line breaking in examples section?

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it - few people read the pdf documentation anyway (most use the html docs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. R CMD check does not analyze / forward all LaTeX warnings.  Yes, in an ideal world it would.
2. It has been the case, always that you should format the \examples{ ... }  section
   well, yourself,
   notably **including** sensible line breaks (and leading spaces) for nice alignment of multi -line examples.

   Use the sources of R itself or recommended packages (or those authored by me, as I do pay attention to this quite a bit), to see good examples  in their *.Rd files.

Remember: The current development sources of R are always web accessible at
    [R (devel) source tree @ svn.r-project.org](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk), i.e. R's standard packages at [R sources src/library](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/).